# How to aggregate for sum the results and group by given field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have documents like this

```
items = [{
        owner: [{ name: "user1" }, { name: "user2" }]
    },
    {
        owner: [{ name: "user1" }, { name: "user2" }]
    },
    {
        owner: [{ name: "user2" }, { name: "user3" }, { name: "user4" }]
    }];
```

So I need to count a number of the same `name` and group by `name` and rank them like this

```
results = [{ name: "user2", count: 3 },
    { name: "user1", count: 2 },
    { name: "user3", count: 1 },
    { name: "user4", count: 1 }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$owner"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$owner.name",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: "$_id",
            count: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            count: -1
        }
    }
])
```

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) can be used to get single name per document, then you need [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to count and [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) for ranking

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AQrUYsj2408)